# Сделать из виджета кнопку

Tags: qt, qt4

Есть виджет, на нем расположены пару лейблов, импровизированная лампочка, показывающая состояние этого виджета. Как можно сделать так, чтобы виджет нажимался как кнопка? Сейчас приходится отлавливать mouseReleaseEvent, но это не совсем то что нужно. Можно унаследоваться от QAbstractButton, но как тогда разместить там лейблы и виджет-лампочку?

Comment: Можно сам виджет сделать кнопкой, добавить туда layout, а в layout добавить ваши лейблы и лампочку.

Comment: @Madisson, И как это будет выглядеть? Мне кажется, что будет кнопка и рядом все виджеты.

Comment: Собственно тск и сделал. Создал класс, наследующийся от QPushButton, там создал лайоуты и туда добавил все что нужно. Вот только цвет кнопки через QPalette не хочет меняться. Под линуксом меняется, под виндой нет.

Comment: Для этого, как по мне, лучше использовать QSS

Comment: http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.6.x/stylesheet-examples.html